# Select Tag for React Updation , trying to display Default Value and Changed Values for Select Tag in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

so i have something like this :

Default value is english anyway , but i wanna display "english" instead of Select there , also if i select any other languages from the menu :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1iDx.png

the value still says "Select" but the content on web page changes anyway , how can i show up the value if i select anything from  tag ?

code until now :

```
const [select, setSelectedOption] = React.useState();

const options = [
  {value: 'English', label: 'English' },
  { value: 'Japanese', label: 'Japanese' },
  { value: 'Chinese', label: 'Chinese' },
  { value: 'Korean', label: 'Korean' },
  { value: 'Spanish', label: 'Spanish' },
  ];

 const handleChange = SelectedOption => {
    setSelectedOption(SelectedOption)
    localStorage.setItem("lang", SelectedOption.value);
    window.location.reload(false)
   // history.push(window.location.pathname);
 };

<div className="Language">
      <h4>Language</h4>
       <Select
            value={select}
            onChange={handleChange}
            options={options}
            default={options[0].value}
        />
  </div>
```

any help would be appreciated !
The thing i am trying is .

1. The page is already in English by default so it should display "English" as selected already in the  Tag
2. If i select any other Language instead of English , then the language should replace English and display.

So i've done this by now :

```
   <h4>Language</h4>
   <Select
        defaultValue={options[0]}
        value={select}
        onChange={handleChange}
        options={options}   
        autoFocus ={true}      
     />           

const handleChange = SelectedOption => {
    setSelectedOption({SelectedOption})
    console.log(SelectedOption)
    localStorage.setItem("lang", SelectedOption.value);
    window.location.reload(false)
 };
```

The value "English" is appearing but when i change to other language the "English" value remains , but page changes it's language.

Comment: anyone up ? any ideas

Comment: Could you provide where you have `select` from `value={select}`?

Comment: const [select, setSelectedOption] = React.useState();

Comment: `setSelectedOption({SelectedOption})` why do you need to have brackets `{}` here? Could you show me the value of `SelectedOption`?

Comment: i thought since we passing object so i kept that , and when i console log that thing i get this : https://prnt.sc/qd3F5t5W4qm0 
but it lasts for seconds and vanishes too

Comment: I think this will create a new object which will be like this `{ SelectedOption: { value: "Korean", label: "Korean" } }`

Answer (score 0):

I hope you manage the value of the 'select' via useState(). If so Reason for this behavior is after you select, component get re-render and set the default value again. To overcome that remove default and set the initial value to value attribute in select.

```
const options = [
{value: 'English', label: 'English' },
{ value: 'Japanese', label: 'Japanese' },
{ value: 'Chinese', label: 'Chinese' },
{ value: 'Korean', label: 'Korean' },
{ value: 'Spanish', label: 'Spanish' },
];

const[select, setSelectedOption] = useState(options[0].value);

const handleChange = SelectedOption => {
  setSelectedOption(SelectedOption)
  localStorage.setItem("lang", SelectedOption.value);
  window.location.reload(false)};

<div className="Language">
    <h4>Language</h4>
    <Select
    value={select}
    onChange={handleChange}
    options={options}   
    autoFocus ={true}      
 />  
</div>
```

Comment: hey there thanks for answer but , it keeps up the value i selected for sometime until page reloads again it dis appears again

Comment: const[select, setSelectedOption] = useState(options[0].value);

const handleChange = SelectedOption => {
    console.log(SelectedOption.value)
    setSelectedOption(SelectedOption.value)
    localStorage.setItem("lang", SelectedOption.value);
    //window.location.reload(true)
   history.push(window.location.pathname);
 };

with this i get the value in console , and it doesnt get refreshed , now just need to display that value in select tag

Comment: @DeepakSarkar what is the <Select> component you are using? Is it Html tag or some component of a library?

Comment: please check my updates post , let me know if thats helpful in other way around

Answer (score -1):

ok i got the answer after trails and error , but this remains fixed to one page only , can anyone help me if these values should be fixed when we navigate to other pages ?
my current solution to the question i posted is this :

```
 const options = [
    {value: 'English', label: 'English' },
    { value: 'Japanese', label: 'Japanese' },
    { value: 'Chinese', label: 'Chinese' },
    { value: 'Korean', label: 'Korean' },
    { value: 'Spanish', label: 'Spanish' },
    ];

  const[select, setSelectedOption] = useState(options[0].value);

  const handleChange = SelectedOption => {
    console.log(SelectedOption.value)
    setSelectedOption(SelectedOption.value)
    localStorage.setItem("lang", SelectedOption.value);
    //window.location.reload(true)
   history.push(window.location.pathname);
 };

<div className="Language">
        <h4>Language</h4>
         <Select
            value={select.value}
            defaultValue = 'English'
            onChange={handleChange}
            options={options}        
          />
              
    </div>
```

The only issue is if i navigate to other pages , The values go away and the  Tag remains empty again

Comment: You should not ask for help/recommendation when you answer a question including yours.

Comment: umm why is that so ? it's just all researching and practicing which would eventually help others too.

Comment: Research should be done before answering. And if you believe the answer is correct and helpful after your research, you can share the answer with others. If you have a specific problem, you can ask a question. There is no problem with that. 
But it is not right to answer a question to ask a question.